# Expand/Collapse sidebar by pressing it's border

Tags: html, css

I am using an edited example from W3Schools for the question.

In the current sidebar, I have added `border-right: 10px solid #ddd;` and I want the sidebar to expand when the user is pressing the border. Is this possible?

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-right: 10px solid #ddd;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px;
  /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
    efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using plain css or with some js?

Comment: @Eric I prefer CSS, but if you have a solution with JS, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution from me :) Hope you like it. As a side button, I have declared a pseudo-class `:after`. I wrote the logic of the code on `jQuery`.

```js
$('.sidenav').on('click', function(e) {
  let height = $(this).height();
  if (e.clientX > $(this).offset().left + 130 &&
      e.clientY < $(this).offset().top + height) {
      $(this).css('width', '30px');
      $('.main').css('margin-left', '50px');
      
  } else {
      $(this).css('width', '');
      $('.main').css('margin-left', '');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  /*border-right: 10px solid #ddd;*/
  transition: .5s;
}

.sidenav:after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
} 

.sidenav:hover:after {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
} 

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
  transition: .5s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

additionally...

```js
var open = false;

function navAction() {

let all_sidebar_a_span = document.querySelectorAll('#sidebar a span');

if (open == true) {
open = false;
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "90px";
document.getElementById("main-container").style.marginLeft = "60px";
document.getElementById("sidebar_btn").style.marginLeft = "0";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "25px";
document.getElementById("main-container").style.transition = "all 0.2s";

Array.from({length: all_sidebar_a_span.length}, (v, k) => k).forEach((index) => {
     let element = all_sidebar_a_span.item(index);
     element.style.opacity = '0';
});
}

else if (open == false) {
open = true;
document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "160px";
document.getElementById("main-container").style.marginLeft = "160px";
document.getElementById("sidebar_btn").style.marginLeft = "70px";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
document.getElementById("main-container").style.transition = "all 0.2s";

Array.from({length: all_sidebar_a_span.length}, (v, k) => k).forEach((index) => {
     let element = all_sidebar_a_span.item(index);
     element.style.opacity = '1';
});

}
  
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

#main-container {
  margin-left: 60px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  /*width: 60px;*/
  width: 90px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  /*
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .3s;
}

#sidebar_btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 0;   
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}

#sidebar_btn:hover {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

#sidebar_btn_dots {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-flow: column;
     align-items: center;
     pointer-events: none;
     height: 100%;
}

#sidebar_btn_dots span {
    font-size: 32px;
}

#sidebar img {
  /*
  width: 60%;
  */
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#sidebar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  */
}
#sidebar a span {
  opacity: 0;
  /*
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  */
}

/*#sidebar:hover a span {
  opacity: 0.2
}
#sidebar a:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}*/

#sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: black !important;
  width: 160px;
}

#sidebar a:hover,
#sidebar a.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: black;
  width: auto;
}

#sidebar a.active {
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div id="main-container">
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
<a href="newsale.php">➕<span class="spanclass">Nytt salg</span></a>
<a class="active" href="#"><span class="spanclass">Hjem</span></a>
<a href="sales.php">‍♂<span class="spanclass">Mine salg</span></a>
<a href="account.php"><span class="spanclass">Konto</span></a>
<a href="logout.php"><span class="spanclass">Logg ut</span></a>
<div id="sidebar_btn" onclick="navAction()">
<div id="sidebar_btn_dots">
<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <!--button class="openbtn" onclick="navAction()">☰ Open Sidebar</button-->  
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool! Just a followup question: Is it possible to have hover effect on the sidebar? So make it a bit darker (to look like a button) when the user hover over?

Comment: Thanks :) Yes, now I will adjust the hover effect.

Comment: check answer please

Comment: Awesome! You are very good. Last question, if I want to include span to display text, is that possible by using this? I have my project here: https://jsfiddle.net/4er26xwp/1/ So when sidebar is expanded, the text does show, and when it is collapsed, only the emojis is shown. Can you do this, or is that hard?

Comment: When the panel is expanded, the text is displayed, and when collapsed, only icons (emojis), without text. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When expanded: Both icons (emojis) and text is displayed* :)

Comment: It's not difficult :) I can do it and add it here as a second solution.

Comment: please check (second snippet). so it was necessary?

Comment: Sorry, maybe you missunderstood me, my bad, but this is with button. I still want to open/close by clicking on the right border as in your first answer.

Comment: Now I understand. Ok. I'll do it now.

Comment: The main thing is to understand each other at any moment :) Check the solution.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I have accepted answer. Just a followup if you have time, can I add three dots in the middle of the bar? So the user easy understand he can click it?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can add dots. Just show me on the screenshot the desired result with the display of dots.

Comment: I've added dots. Position can be controlled by the `align-items` rule in the `#sidebar_btn_dots` selector. Also, you have the ability to customize the `font-size` of the dots.

Comment: Can one change the dots to go vertical insted of horizontal also?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna solve it with JS you can do it by toggeling:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wind">
    <div id="sidenav" onclick="closeNav()">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="#services">Services</a>
      <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
      <p>Scroll down the page to see the result.</p>
      <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html> 



<style>
.mystyle {
  width: 0px !important;
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-right: 10px solid #ddd;
}

#sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

#sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>

<script>
function closeNav() {    
   var element = document.getElementById("sidenav");
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}



</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```